# go https client certificate

Tags: go, https, client-certificates

Trying to migrate a working java code with https client certificate authentication to golang but getting tls handshake error

go version go1.12.9 linux/amd64

client certificate details

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in p12file.p12 
Enter Import Password:
MAC: sha1, Iteration 2048
MAC length: 20, salt length: 8
PKCS7 Encrypted dat..
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: test
    localKeyID:..
subject=CN = *....com
issuer=C = US, O = DigiCert Inc...

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Certificate bag
Bag Attributes: <No Attributes>
subject=C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = RapidS...
issuer=C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
....
```

working Java code

```
url = new URL(https_url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
//geting 405 status - so its working

able to establish https connection with this arg -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=./p12file.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
```

golang issue (removed error handling part)

```
fb, err := ioutil.ReadFile(p12file)
b, err := pkcs12.ToPEM(fb, password)

cert, err := tls.X509KeyPair(pem.EncodeToMemory(b[0]), pem.EncodeToMemory(b[2]))
//b[0] and b[1] is CERTIFICATE, b[2] is PRIVATE KEY, with 1&2 getting 'private key does not match public key'

//also tried 
// openssl pkcs12 -in ./p12file.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out certfile.crt 
// openssl pkcs12 -in ./p12file.p12 -nocerts -nodes -out keyfile.key
// cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(certFile, keyFile)
tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
    Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{cert},
    InsecureSkipVerify: true,
}
tlsConfig.BuildNameToCertificate()
transport := &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig}
client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}

resp, err := client.Get(url)
```

getting 'remote error: tls: handshake failure'

Comment: Presumably b[1] is the intermediate that signed b[0]? If so, you can't just omit that. The server can't construct the complete chain if you do. Try `tls.X509KeyPair(append(pem.EncodeToMemory(b[0]), pem.EncodeToMemory(b[1])...), pem.EncodeToMemory(b[2]))`.

Comment: Working, thanks, Please post as answer